# Twitter Oauth Request Token

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have tried looking through all the posts on the topic. None of them couldn't resolve my issue. I have been trying to solve this since days. Can anyone help me figure out my mistake. I am using Nativescript's fetch module to make the request and nativesctipt's tool box library crypto-js HMAC SHA1 to encode.

Signature String: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%%26oauth_nonce%3D5yyu34cdxeharzht2rtn9iv414qmb5kk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1523751460%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26oauth_callback=https%253A%252F%252Ftest.com

Request:
POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="5yyu34cdxeharzht2rtn9iv414qmb5kk",oauth_callback="https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%0D%0A",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1523751460",oauth_consumer_key="consumer key",oauth_signature="signature",oauth_version="1.0"

I am now getting a code 32 error. Can anyone please help me with the issue.